# Color Code .inc in Dreamweaver CS4 Mac

Tags: php, dreamweaver, color-codes

I have done this in all my previous versions, but I can't get it working in CS4.  I have updated the MMDocumentTypes.xml file to add inc to the php section.  Restarting Dreamweaver does not help.  I even updated the Extensions.txt file, and that still does not work.

Has anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a workaround to do that on Windows:
https://superuser.com/questions/115614/how-make-dreamweaver-color-the-code-as-php-for-inc-files
Not sure if it's working on Mac too. Also here's a [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddhe53W1FHk).

*update: [It's working on Mac, too.](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16410.html)*

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue, but on a mac on cs5.5 - For the life of me, I couldn't get it to work, but then I read that there are actually 4 files that need to be edited.

```
~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Dreamweaver CS5.5/en_US/Configuration/DocumentTypes/MMDocumentTypes.xml

~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Dreamweaver CS5.5/en_US/Configuration/Extensions.txt
```

**and**

```
Applications/Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5/Configuration/DocumentTypes/MMDocumentTypes.xml

Applications/Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5/Configuration/Extensions.txt
```

On a mac at least, the trouble was that the ~/Library/ files are hidden by default. So I had to unhide them via terminal, then make the changes.

It now works.

I hope that helps at least a little. Good luck!